# How to slice a dataframe based on values with nulls

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy, slice

I have a simple but a bit complicated issue with pandas slicing, the problem is that I want to slice the dataframe **based on col3** as the following:

```
     col1    col2    col3
0     43      n        X 
1     14      k        X

2     2       z        Y
3     24      q        Y
4     25      w       NaN
5     36      e        Y

6     4       t        Z
7     73      h        Z

8     25      g        Y
9     53      s       NaN
10    64      f       NaN
```

Is there any way I can slice using numpy (or any fast method) with considering the null values? since am dealing with 1M+ records dataframe and I would like the fastest way to do it.

My current solution:

```
data = {'col1': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12],'col2':['x','y','z','t','e','w','r','u','p','y','r','u'],'col3':['X',None,'X','Y',None,'Y' ,'Y','Z','Z','Y',None,None]}
dff = pd.DataFrame(data)
 
for i in dff.col3.unique():
    ind = np.where((dff.col3 == i))
    print(dff.iloc[ind])

Output:
   col1 col2 col3
0     1    x    X
2     3    z    X
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [col1, col2, col3]
Index: []
   col1 col2 col3
3     4    t    Y
5     6    w    Y
6     7    r    Y
9    10    y    Y
   col1 col2 col3
7     8    u    Z
8     9    p    Z
```

[This's how I want the output to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivBPb.png)

I saw [this nice solution](https://towardsdatascience.com/pandas-dataframe-group-by-consecutive-same-values-128913875dba) but it does not work in my case since I have nulls in my column

Edit:

Sorry let me clarify more about nulls:

1- If NaN surrounded by X values it belongs to X.

2- If NaN between X and Y it can belong to both of them, the rows could by duplicates in X and Y slices.

Comment: how do you know if NaN belongs to X or Y or Z?

Comment: @NoobVB Good question, 1- If NaN surrounded by X values it belongs to X    2- If NaN between X and Y it can belong to both of them, the rows could by duplicates in X and Y.

Comment: Let's say there is NaN in index 6. Should it belong in Y or Z?

Comment: @NuriTaş Belongs to both, Please check my comment above.